# PHP MapReduce Mongodb returning all the map results as well as the reduced set?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to get a count of how many 'Domains' for each 'whoisPreset',

eg:
542b151053980df766000000:10
542b151053980df766000002:3

etc..

Simplified Document

```
> db.Domain.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542b152653980d2467000000"),
    "whoisPreset" : ObjectId("542b151053980df766000000"),
    "whoisPresetUpdated":false
}
```

MapReduce in php

```
        $map = new MongoCode("function() { emit(this.whoisPreset,1); }");

        $reduce = new MongoCode("function(k, vals) { ".
            "var sum = 0;".
            "for (var i in vals) {".
            "sum += vals[i];".
            "}".
            "return sum; }");

        $mapReduce = $this->Couch()->command(
            [
            "mapreduce" => 'Domain',
            "map" => $map,
            "reduce" => $reduce,
            "query" =>
                [
                    'whoisPreset'=>['$ne'=>null,'$exists'=>true],
                    '$or'=>[
                        ["whoisPresetUpdated"=>['$exists'=>false]],
                        ["whoisPresetUpdated" => false],
                        ["whoisPresetUpdated"=>null]
                    ]
                ],
            "out" => ["merge" => "whoisPresetCounts"]
        ]);

        $counts = $this->Couch()->selectCollection($mapReduce['result'])->find();


        foreach ($counts as $tupple) {
            print_r($tupple);
        }
```

Then in the result, I seem to be getting the output of every omit, as well as the reduced result

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b152653980d2467000000
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b1e5d53980d8c67000001
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b1f0f53980d8b67000000
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b1f7b53980db967000006
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b1ff453980d8b67000007
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542c15f853980dc904000001
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542c17ed53980db605000001
        )

    [value] => 
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542c6bf053980d1013000000
        )

    [value] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b151053980df766000000
        )

)
Array
(
    [_id] => 
    [value] => 7
)
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 542b151053980df766000000
        )

    [value] => 8
)
```

Also at the bottom there is a null _id with a 7 count, that i don't get..

There are 8 documents, essentially identical to the first example given there..

Comment: Is the problem possibly the "merge" on the output collection from a previous attempt? The only value you are emitting from the mapper is `1` and at worst the "reduce" output is `0`, yet there are several blank values in here or other things. Try to just output to a new collection. Both mapper and reducer are outputting a single value here so that part looks okay. The merge would seem to be the problem.

Comment: Did you at some point run the mapReduce command without the specified `query` argument? Alternatively, if you drop the merged output collection and re-run the mapReduce job, does it still include the unexpected results (with the `null` `_id`?).